# How to exit Vim, without saving changes using the shortcut Ctrl-Q?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, quit

I have tried several things to set the keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to exit Vim without saving any changes (i.e., what is normally bound to `:qa!`). I have tried adding:

```
inoremap <C-q> <esc>:qa!<cr>               " quit discarding changes
nnoremap <C-q> :qa!<cr>
```

to my `~/.vimrc` based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241784/27613) on Unix & Linux StackExchange. This failed as when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> nothing happened. I have also tried:

```
map <C-Q> :qa!
```

and:

```
map <C-Q> ":qa!
```

neither worked. Any ideas what I need to do to set this keybinding? If it is at all relevant my platform is Fedora 25 and I installed the latest Vim from my own Open Build Service repository — https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:fusion809/vim-redhat.

Comment: What do you get when you type `i<C-v><C-q>`? If nothing shows up, it's something with your terminal.

Comment: `i` starts insert mode in Vim, so I must admit I'm confused what you're expecting <C-v><C-q> will do afterwards. <C-v> is bound in my `~/.vimrc` to paste.

Comment: In insert mode, `<C-v>` allows you to insert a literal character with no side effects. It's just a nice way to test whether or not the keystroke ever gets to vim in the first place

Comment: Well I've tested out `<C-q>` in gvim too with those edits to my Vimrc and it still doesn't quit Vim so it's not due to my terminal that this keybinding doesn't work.

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7884226) provides a solution to the problem.

Comment: I spoke too soon, it doesn't work in the CLI. It just causes Vim to go to Visual Block (shown in this screenshot http://imgur.com/a/wxE6v).

Comment: Oops no that was due to another line in my `~/.vimrc`. I am gonna write up an answer with what worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is what fixed this problem for me, I unknowingly had  bound to something else in my `~/.vimrc`, when I removed it and added:

```
silent !stty -ixon > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
map <C-Q> :qa!<CR>
```

to my `~/.vimrc` file this keybinding worked properly.

Comment: If your problem was that something else was mapped to `<c-q>` I don't see why you need the first line (`silent !stty...`)?

Comment: Note: In my testing, this leaves soft flow control turned off on the terminal even after you exit Vim, so ctrl+s and ctrl+q don't work to pause long outputs afterwards. It might be a good idea to add an autocommand for VimLeave or something to `stty ixon`. Alternatively, if you never use flow control and it gets in your way, you can do the stty in your bashrc (or equivalent) instead of vimrc, and get the bonus of using ctrl+s for forward-searching your history in bash and other readline shells.